# Java 8 stream groupingBy

Tags: java, java-stream

Подскажите как преобразовать:

```
Map<String, List<Pet>> pets = petList
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pet::getType));
```

в

```
Map<String, PetsHouse>
```

при помощи `stream`?
Или я сильно заморачиваюсь и решить без использования стримов?

`PetHouse` - это просто некая обертка над листом

```
List<Pet> petList;
PetHouse house = new PetHouse(petList);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё решаемо:

```
Map<String, List<Pet>> pets = petList
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Pet::getType,
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), PetHouse::new)
        ));
```

Comment: Вот, вот то что я хотел!! Спасибо!

Answer (score 5):

```
Map<String, PetHouse> m = pets.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, e -> new PetHouse(e.getValue())));
```

Comment: Спасибо, так я и решил! Просто я думал что можно както этот маппинг провести еще на уровне группировки